# LibGDX Vector3 Lerp issue

Tags: java, vector, libgdx, linear-interpolation

I am using LibGDX and trying to lerp between two Vector3s... however, when I do this, its not linear, its sort of easing it in an exponential way. I do not want this, I want it purely linear!

This is so my model can follow a set of Vector3s, like following a path.

A code snippet of my update method is here:

```
public void update(float delta) {
    if (!this.pathQueue.isEmpty() && this.currentDestination == null) {
        this.currentDestination = this.pathQueue.poll();
        this.alpha = 0;
    }

    Vector3 position = new Vector3();
    position = this.model.transform.getTranslation(position);

    if (this.currentDestination != null) {
        this.alpha += this.speed * delta; 
        if (this.alpha >= 1) {
            this.currentDestination = this.pathQueue.poll();
            this.alpha = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(alpha);

        //position.interpolate(this.currentDestination.getPosition(), this.alpha, Interpolation.linear);
        position.lerp(this.currentDestination.getPosition(), this.alpha);
        //I have tried interpolate and lerp, same effect.
        this.model.transform.setTranslation(position.x, 0, position.z);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Edit:

I've changed my code to an even simpler problem, and using a FIXED new Vector3(5,0,5) vector:

```
    public void update(float delta) {

    if (!this.pathQueue.isEmpty() && this.currentDestination == null) {
        this.currentDestination = this.pathQueue.poll();
        this.alpha = 0;
    }

    if (this.currentDestination != null) {
        this.alpha += this.speed * delta; 

        this.currentPosition.lerp(new Vector3(5,0,5), this.alpha);
        this.model.transform.setTranslation(this.currentPosition.x, 0, this.currentPosition.z);
    }
}
```

It still causes problems. Same thing happens! I'm so boggled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is this:

```
position.lerp(this.currentDestination.getPosition(), this.alpha);
```

You are updating from position to destination, after each frame you update position, so on the next frame, you're effectively interpolating from your new position to the end.  (Thus as you get closer to the destination you have a smaller difference between positions to interpolate between.)

I think you're updating `alpha` correctly, so you want to interpolate from your start to your destination on each frame.  So, I think resetting the "position" vector to the start before interpolating between start and end should give you the behavior you want.

Comment: Yes you are right, I also think its something like this. But even if I do this:

Vector3 newPosition = this.previousDestination.lerp(this.currentDestination.getPosition(), this.alpha);
   this.model.transform.setTranslation(newPosition.x, 0, newPosition.z);

it doesn't work. It seems this.previousDestination is being updated every time lerp is called, which could be normal behaviour?

Comment: I think that modifies previousDestination.  You probably need to copy or clone the previous destination into position (maybe?).  Print current/previous/position in your println() to see if/how any of them are changing ...

Comment: i've edited my question for an even simpler version of the problem. its 6am now, ill carry on with this tomorrow